# Display unresponsive in one sketch, while working in another

Tags: arduino-uno, display

I'm using a DOGM163 Display. It works in a DEMO sketch provided by the manufacturer but not in my sketch. This is strange, because I am using the same library specific commands as in the example.

I think of the following possibilities:

1. Something inside the other libraries I use in my sketch is hindering the dogm from working (perhaps by fiddling around with the ports connected to the display).
2. I've got a power problem which surfaces when doing more than just that demo.
3. Timing is botched.
4. Something with my wiring is wrong. Perhaps in conjunction with 1).

I'm using:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include "newsched.h"
#include "dplan.h"
#include <EEPROM.h>
#include <PinChangeInt.h>
#include <dogm_7036.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <OneWire.h>
#include "lampcontrol.h"
```

Power seems to be ok, as I'm receiving all debug messages via serial correctly.

The display is sharing its port with a port expander and a SD-port. But removing the SD-port doesn't change the problem.

**Update (Part1)**
Here comes the code, which works:

http://pastebin.com/eXUVzeV8

This is a slightly modified manufacturer example. But it does what it should do. It displays the demo text.

Here comes, what doesn't work:

[Main sketch](http://pastebin.com/MCsyDUXL)
[newsched.h](http://pastebin.com/1xSNGhCs)
[newsched.cpp](http://pastebin.com/UCPuyG08)
[display.h](http://pastebin.com/cKCErjHR)
[display.cpp](http://pastebin.com/dvVWdJAK)
[menu.h](http://pastebin.com/278UYXGu)
[menu.cpp](http://pastebin.com/PhYikzBP)

The other source files, 19 in total!, can be posted on request, but as you can see from newsched.cpp I already disabled most of the code to narrow down the error.

What exactly means "not work"? Not work means, the display seems to be turned off. The LED backlight is on, but you cannot see the grey character boxes (due to display bias), which appear in the working code sample.

**Update 2**
Schematic: [image: Schematic]

Comment: What you should do next is show us your wiring (schematic) and sketch.

Comment: My initial response is that this is too broad to be answered. For one thing you say it "works" in one case but "not in my sketch" in another. A lot more detail would be helpful, describing what "work" and "not work" refer to, exactly. For more help I would suggest posting the code (or a link to it if it is very long) and also your debugging messages, which you say you got. Presumably if you got debugging messages it "works" to some extent (that is, it doesn't hang completely). `But removing the SD-port doesn't change the problem.` - again, what problem?

Comment: That sounds like a mighty complex program with that number of files. Have you considered you might simply be running out of memory? I notice you have never used _F(...) around any of your string constants to lock them into flash...

Comment: I added a bunch of code and schematic now. Let me know, if you want to see more source files...

Comment: @Majenko: No, that _F-feature is new to me. String constants are predominant in the menu class. The other classes deal with small portions of measurement data and control tasks. What makes the project big is the use of a lot of peripherals over the three stooges: SPI, I2C and 1-wire bus. To keep the overview I make a class at least for each peripheral unit. Now, I'll have a look onto the F-thing...

Comment: The `_F()` thing stops the strings being copied into RAM.  It's a macro that makes then into PROGMEM items so that PROGMEM-enabled functions are used to access them instead of non-PROGMEM ones that require the string to first be copied into RAM to access them. It's all because the Flash and RAM are on completely separate data/address buses.

Comment: Ok, got it. It's just a PROGMEM macro. How convenient.

Comment: To my discomfort the F-macro only works where the functions are overloaded appropriately. Which is not the case for the display routines. But the hint was good, as I had forgotten the fact, that strings are copied to ram at program start.